# Looping through dynamic forms and submitting each onclick with Ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am dynamically populating form(s) in my view (MVC) and I can have one or many forms on the same page. Each form is uniquely named, however the field variables in each form remain the same.

It works a treat with each form having its own submit button and passing the input to my Post Controller method, but now I need to add the option to submit all or one form by clicking the "next page" link. As I already have JQuery loading, I am trying to do this with Ajax and Json but I am stuck.

View

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model IEnumerable<Template.Models.GetViewModel>
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "About me";
   ViewBag.Page = Model.First().PageNumber;
 }
@Html.AntiForgeryToken();
@foreach (var q in Model.OrderBy(o => o.QuestionRanking))
{
    var qtype = q.QuestionTypeId;
    Html.BeginForm("ViewQuestion", "Question", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = @q.ShowHide + " form-horizontal", id = @q.FormNumber, role = "form" });
    <div>
    <h1>@q.QuestionRanking. @q.Question1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.TextArea("Answer", q.Answer, new { @class = "form-control", rows = "4", cols = "10" })
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="@q.FormNumber" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save answer" />
</div>
<hr />
Html.EndForm();
}
<p>
   @Html.ActionLink("Previous", "ViewQuestion", new { page = ViewBag.Page - 1 }) |
   @Html.ActionLink("Next", "ViewQuestion", new { page = ViewBag.Page + 1 })
</p>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
}
```

The controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewQuestion([Bind(Include = "QuestionId, UserId")] ResponseViewModel responseViewModel)
    {

        var page = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["page"];
        var newAnswer = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["Answer"];
        var re = new Response
                {
                    Answer = newAnswer,
                    UserId = responseViewModel.UserId,
                    QuestionId = responseViewModel.QuestionId,
                };
                _db.Responses.Add(re);
                _db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I haven't gotten very far with my script and I am lost as to how to get the values to my controller;

```
<script>
  function postValues() {
    var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
    $( "#results" ).text( str );
    }
</script>
```

Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To use ajax you can convert your forms using the following

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("ViewQuestion","Question",null,new AjaxOptions{ options here },
new     { @class = @q.ShowHide + " form-horizontal", id = @q.FormNumber, role = "form"
 }))
   {
       @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
<div>
    <h1>@q.QuestionRanking. @q.Question1</h1>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
@Html.TextArea("Answer", q.Answer, new { @class = "form-control", rows = "4", 
cols =     "10" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="submit" name="@q.FormNumber" class="btn btn-primary" 
value="Save   answer" />
</div>
<hr />


   }
```

then you can use jquery to submit each form

```
$('form').each(function(){
$(this).submit();
});
```

with regards to @Html.AntiForgeryToken(); this should be within each form, and if you want to use it you need to add [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] to your controller action

Comment: This is a great help, but can you give me an idea of the AjaxOptions, please? I have searched and find things like OnComplete=some action, but I am wondering if I need to bind all the fields as there are more fields, mostly hidden ones on my form, that I left out for simplicity.

Comment: Not all the fields need to be used, the minimum amount would be something like: new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "ID TO UPDATE", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace})